# Using xs:alternative in Visual Studio

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to use `xs:alternative` in an XSD, however Visual Studio 2010 does not recognise xs:alternative as a valid child for xs:element. I am using `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` as my namespace.

I have tried some of the examples I have found online and VS2010 does not like those either.
When I run the document through W3C validator, it also does not recognise it.

Am I missing something or is `xs:alternative` not available yet?

Answer (score 2):

`<xs:alternative />` is part of the XSD 1.1 specification.

No Microsoft product yet supports XSD 1.1.